# EF Core - EntityTypeBuilder One to Many Relationship?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am a bit confused, about how to do relationships in EF Core 2.1. I been doing it the fluent way.

I have

```
public class Employee : IdentityUser
{
    public int BranchId { get; set; }
    public Branch Branch { get; set; }

}

 public class Branch
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        public Company Company { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }

public class EmployeerConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Employee>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Employee> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Employees");
    }
}

public class BranchConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Branch>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Branch> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
            builder.Property(x => x.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

            builder.HasMany(x => x.Employees);

            builder.ToTable("Branches");
        }
    }
```

All the examples I seen mostly to use dbcontext model builder, but that way is no longer needed as you can now use split it up as I done.

I done my relationships 2 ways first for Company and Branch I don't even specify the relationship yet went I build my db it knows, however when I try to do that with Employee and Branch the relationship was not formed.

This made me add `builder.HasMany(x => x.Employees)` in the branch config and now the relationship works, however I am not sure if I have specify something in the Employee area to make to complete?

I also don't know if I need to still add virtual to my collections anymore and why if I don't use ToTable() and build my db, all the table names are abbreviated, I thought that was automatic.

Comment: did you get this resolved? I am getting exactly the same issue

Answer (score 1):

EmployeerConfig is fine you can add key if yoy want

For Branch Config add this line hope this'll help you.

```
     builder.HasMany(x => x.Employee).WithOne(b => b.Branch).HasForeignKey(b => b.BranchId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be multiple ways to do this. You can specify the relationship in `EmployeeConfig.Configure` or in `BranchConfig.Configure`, or in the `DbContext`'s `OnModelCreating` method. I haven't tested to see what kind of behavior you get from specifying it in multiple places, but it's probably fine as long as it's consistent. However, in order to make maintenance easier, you probably want to specify it in only one place. I think the natural place is the DbContext, as this is a piece of information related to multiple entities, not just one. If you'd prefer to put it in one of the configuration files, I would suggest that putting it in the parent entity seems more natural.

Here is how you would specify it in `EmployeeConfig.Configure`:

```
builder.HasOne<Branch>(e => e.Branch).WithMany(b => b.Employees).HasForeignKey(e => e.BranchId);
```

That says that the `Employee` has one `Branch`, that the `Branch` has many `Employees`, and that the dependent entity (`Employee`) has a foreign key pointing back at the `Branch`, called `BranchId`.

Here is how you would specify it in `BranchConfig.Configure`:

```
builder.HasMany<Employee>(b => b.Employees).WithOne(e => e.Branch).HasForeignKey(e => e.BranchId);
```

Which says the same thing: the `Branch` has many `Employees`, each of which has one `Branch`, and that the dependent entity (`Employee`) has a foreign key called `BranchId`.

Here is how you would specify it in `DbContext.OnModelCreating`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Branch>().HasMany<Employee>(b => b.Employees).WithOne(e => e.Branch).HasForeignKey(e => e.BranchId);
```

or

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().HasOne<Branch>(e => e.Branch).WithMany(b => b.Employees).HasForeignKey(e => e.BranchId);
```